# erase lines on image canvas without effecting background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, struts2

I am writing a web application where I need to annotate image. For that I am using canvas of html5. Thanks for the web, I found many codes which are similar. But I got a problem after developing the code.

```
context.clearRect(pos.x,pos.y,pos.x,pos.y);
```

This is the code I am using for erasing the lines in canvas. What I am expecting the code to do is erase where the mouse pointer is. But what code is doing is erasing the line even though the mouse pointer is somewhere nearer to the line.

edit:I found the problem with erasing. The syntax of clearRect() is

```
context.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
```

As I am giving pos.x and pos.y as width and height respectively it is erasing a vast area. Now I changed those two values as 5,5 and I am able to erase where ever the pointer is.

Also I need to save the annotated image after annotating it completely. I am keeping the images the background of canvas. And I am drawing lines in canvas. When click view image I am able to see only the lines. Please check my code tell me how to do both these operations. here is my code.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Success: Upload User Image</title>   
    <style>
        canvas { background:url("images/<s:property value="userImageFileName"/>") ;
                 background-size: 100% 100%;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    </style>    
</head>

<body>

    <h2>utStruts2 File Upload Example</h2>
    <img id="result" src="images/<s:property value="userImageFileName"/>" width="565" height="584" class="annotatable"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="565" height="584" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" >
        Please use a modern browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari
    </canvas>
    <input type="button" value="draw" onClick="draw()">
    <input type="button" value="eraser" onClick="erase()">

    <canvas id="canvas2" width="565" height="584" hidden="true"></canvas>
    <script>
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');           
          var coord = document.getElementById('coord');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
          var cantext2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

        function draw(){
            mode="draw";    
            operate(mode);
        }

        function erase(){
            mode="erase";
            operate(mode);
        }

        function operate(mode)
        {
              var mousedown = false;
              context.strokeStyle = '#0000FF';
              context.lineWidth = 5;

              canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
                  var pos = fixPosition(e, canvas);
                  mousedown = true;
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);                       
                  //return false;
              };

              canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
                  var pos = fixPosition(e, canvas);                 
                  if (mousedown) {
                      if(mode=="draw"){
                          context.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
                          context.stroke();
                      }
                      if(mode=="erase"){
                          context.clearRect(pos.x,pos.y,pos.x,pos.y);
                          context2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
                          context.clearRect(0, 0, 565, 584);
                          context.drawImage("images/<s:property value="userImageFileName"/>", 0, 0);
                          context.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0); 
                      }
                  }
              };

              canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
                  mousedown = false;
              };

              function fixPosition(e, gCanvasElement) {
                    var x;
                    var y;

                    x = e.pageX;
                    y = e.pageY;

                    x -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
                    y -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;

                    return {x:x, y:y};
                }
        }  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearRect` accepts the following arguments: `(xpos, ypos, width, height)`

*Problem(s):*
In your `canvas.onmousemove` function (in mode "erase") you have: `context.clearRect(pos.x,pos.y,pos.x,pos.y);`

Hmm, that can't be right..

Then, after you've erased an area-size depending on your mouse position, you copy the remainder of `context` to some buffer-canvas `context2`: `context2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);`

After which you clear the whole drawing canvas: `context.clearRect(0, 0, 565, 584);`

*Solution(s)*:
Once you have fixed the above (so that the mousepointer works as an eraser) you want to add a function to combine/export/store your annotated image:

Use your buffer `context2` to draw your (original) image on first, then on top of that, you draw your annotation image (both using `drawImage()`) (think of layers).

Finally you use the `.toDataURL()` method to output the combined image from your `context2` buffer (and send off the result (a base64 encoded data-url which is a simple string) using AJAX etc).

*Also:*

- you might want to know you don't need to markup your buffer, just create it in memory: 
  `var canvas2=document.createElement('canvas');`
- your var `mode` is leaking into global (I would just issue `operate('draw')` etc and save the waisted operations, in benefit of better UX responsiveness ('less work to do')).